# 02 Acura rsx type s

Tags: transmission

6speed manual transmission.  Car being on or off, it won’t shift into the top gears of the shift box (1st 3rd and 5th) but WILL shift into all the other gears. What would be reason for this prob? What’s wrong m?

Comment: The linkage out of adjustment?

Comment: @SolarMike Tinworm upper gear rot.  Been a Honda problem since Jesus left Chicago.  Or maybe the shift linkage . . .